# Pivoting the rows and columns but with a condition on a PASSFAIL column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape, tidyr

I have a data frame like this

```
NUM <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1)
ID <- c("DJ45","DJ45","DJ45","DJ46","DJ46","DJ46","DJ47","DJ47","DJ47","DJ48")
Type <- c("A", "F", "C", "B", "D", "A", "E", "C", "F", "D")
Points1 <- c(9.2,60.8,22.9,1012.7,18.7,11.1,67.2,63.1,16.7,58.4)
Points2 <- c(19.2,0.8,2.9,12.7,188.7,114.1,7.2,66.1,46.7,508.4)
PASSFAIL <- c("PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "FAIL")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,NUM,Type,Points1,Points2,PASSFAIL)
```

df1:

```
    ID NUM Type Points1 Points2 PASSFAIL
1  DJ45   1    A     9.2    19.2     PASS
2  DJ45   2    F    60.8     0.8     PASS
3  DJ45   3    C    22.9     2.9     FAIL
4  DJ46   1    B    12.7    12.7     PASS
5  DJ46   2    D    18.7   188.7     FAIL
6  DJ46   3    A    11.1   114.1     PASS
7  DJ47   1    E    67.2     7.2     PASS
8  DJ47   2    C    63.1    66.1     FAIL
9  DJ47   3    F    16.7    46.7     FAIL
10 DJ48   1    D    58.4   508.4     FAIL
```

I am trying to obtain an output that takes the rows in "Type" column to convert it to individual columns with values filled using a condition on the PASSFAIL column and that is (If PASSFAIL = PASS, use the values of Points1 column and if PASSFAIL = FAIL, use the values from Points2 column)

My Desired Output is

```
    ID   NUM   A    B    C    D    E    F    PASSFAIL 
1  DJ45   1    9.2  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     PASS
2  DJ45   2    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   60.8   PASS
3  DJ45   3    NA   NA   2.9  NA   NA   NA     FAIL
4  DJ46   1    NA 1012.7 NA   NA   NA   NA     PASS
5  DJ46   2    NA   NA   NA  188.7 NA   NA     FAIL
6  DJ46   3    11.1 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     PASS
7  DJ47   1    NA   NA   NA   NA   67.2 NA     PASS
8  DJ47   2    NA   NA   66.1 NA   NA   NA     FAIL
9  DJ47   3    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   46.7   FAIL
10 DJ48   1    NA   NA   NA  508.4 NA   NA     FAIL
```

I tried to do it this way but I am just not knowing how to use my condition in this code.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, NUM) %>%
  mutate(id2 = sequence(n())) %>%
  spread(Type, Points1)
```

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `reshape2`:

```
df1$pick <- ifelse(df1$PASSFAIL == "PASS", df1$Points1, df1$Points2)
newdf <- dcast(df1, ID+NUM~Type, value.var="pick")
data.frame(newdf, PASSFAIL=df1[,"PASSFAIL"])
#      ID NUM    A      B    C     D    E    F PASSFAIL
# 1  DJ45   1  9.2     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA     PASS
# 2  DJ45   2   NA     NA   NA    NA   NA 60.8     PASS
# 3  DJ45   3   NA     NA  2.9    NA   NA   NA     FAIL
# 4  DJ46   1   NA 1012.7   NA    NA   NA   NA     PASS
# 5  DJ46   2   NA     NA   NA 188.7   NA   NA     FAIL
# 6  DJ46   3 11.1     NA   NA    NA   NA   NA     PASS
# 7  DJ47   1   NA     NA   NA    NA 67.2   NA     PASS
# 8  DJ47   2   NA     NA 66.1    NA   NA   NA     FAIL
# 9  DJ47   3   NA     NA   NA    NA   NA 46.7     FAIL
# 10 DJ48   1   NA     NA   NA 508.4   NA   NA     FAIL
```

It helps to create a new column with the data that is going to be made into the "wide" format. We do that by using `ifelse` to choose `Points1` for `"PASS"` and `Points2` for not `"PASS"`. `dcast` is called on the `ID` and `NUM` columns to go wide with the "Type" column. The `PASSFAIL` column is attached to the reshape output to finish.

Comment: Thank you so much. this works like charm. Yes, I edited my desired output. It was a mistake on my part.

Comment: And piping: `df1 %>% mutate(pick=ifelse(PASSFAIL=="PASS",Points1,Points2)) %>% spread(Type,pick) %>% select(-Points1,-Points2)` or something

Comment: @Pierre, If the passfail column has one more category say "AVG", and I use Points 2 for this. How to deal with it? How can I modify the code? I just applied to one of the real data set that I have and it has 3 categories and hence was curious to know.

Comment: It would not change anything. Points2 column is used for any value that is not PASS